# Missing man pages under Debian WSL

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed the WSL version of Debian and changed the default shell to zsh. Now I cant find the man pages. the ZSH shell doesn't recognize any command related to the man pages.

I've tried

```
man-db
man
```

and always get this

```
zsh: command not found: man-db
```

How can I get the manpages under WSL Debian using ZSH?

I thought that maybe the manpages are not automatically installed with the WSL package, even though this would be odd.

My other guess is that it has to do with using **oh-my-zsh**.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as WSL as well and there is no such problem. When I type

```
man man
```

I get the man help pages.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you show us what command you're issuing and what the response is?

Comment: `man-db` is a package, `man` is a command. Do you get `command not found` when using `man` as well? Could you please add the output of `print -rC1 -- $path` (from your `zsh` shell)?  Are you setting `$path` or `$PATH` in your shell's startup files (typically `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the [man-db](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=man-db) package, it's missing in WSL.

Update the package index and install the package with `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install man-db
```